# How to encode ecto query results into JSON quickly in IEx?

Tags: elixir, ecto

What is an easy and quick way to encode some Ecto struct from a query in IEx?  I'm not looking for how to implement `@derive` in my application code, just a quick way to dump to JSON quickly pull some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following worked for me. One needs to drop `:__meta__` and any not loaded associations.

```
Repo.all(Event) |> Enum.map(&(Map.from_struct(&1) |> Map.drop([:__meta__]))) |> Jason.encode!()
```